# LUIS Import Dataset: BadArgument: Dataset object cannot be null. Parameter name: dataSet

Tags: json, azure-language-understanding

Good day community, I am using LUIS to train a data set to let it classified between different meaning of the words. After I've done trained, I want to import a set of data to let it test. There is a batch testing options for me to import a json file, however it keeps showing this error: 
`BadArgument: Dataset object cannot be null. Parameter name: dataSet`

I have already follow the json format that it gave which is like this:

```
[
{
    "text": "hey dad, are you hungry?",
    "intent": "None",
    "entities":
    [
    {
        "entity": "FamilyMember",
        "startPos": 4,
        "endPos": 6
    }
    ]
},
{
    .
    .
    .
}
]
```

My json file has the format like this:

```
[
{
"text" : "Hello"
"intent": "Greetings"
},
{
"text" : "I want bread"
"intent": "Request"
}
]
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? The training doesn't include any entities so I did not put it into my json file.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to provide the `entities` attribute and give it an empty array, otherwise you'll receive a different error. Regarding your format, you're missing commas after your `text` attributes.

```
[
  {
    "text" : "Hello",
    "intent": "Greetings",
    "entities": []
  },
  {
    "text" : "I want bread",
    "intent": "Request",
    "entities": []
  }
]
```

When I used the above code the batch test successfully completed for me.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry I haven't been online for a few days! But yes I did miss the comma, thank you very much!!!